# jQuery script not available in AJAX loaded page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an anonymous jQuery function that looks like this:

```
( function( $ ) {

    "use strict";

    var CHEF = window.CHEF || {};

    CHEF.fancyTitler = function() {
        if( $( '.k-fancy-title' ).length ) {
            $( '.k-fancy-title' ).wrap( '<div class="k-fancy-title-wrap" />' );
        }

    }
    // + a bunch of other functions inside

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        CHEF.fancyTitler();
        // + a bunch of other function inits
    } );

} )(jQuery);
```

...then I load some content on to the page by using AJAX. Everything is fine regarding content loading, however `.k-fancy-title` element doesn't get wrapped. It's kinda obvious that I need to reload/re-call/whatever my anonymous function in order to wrap ajax loaded content with DIV (`.k-fancy-title-wra`p).

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you not just recall this: `CHEF.fancyTitler();` when you load in your content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your success handler from the ajax call you could bind jQuery's global ajax success event, [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    chef.fancyTitler();
});
```

However you're going to have to alter your `fancyTitler` method to not re-wrap already wrapped elements.

Something like this

```
CHEF.fancyTitler = function() {
    $('.k-fancy-title').each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        if(!el.parents('.k-fancy-title-wrap').length)
        {
            el.wrap('<div class="k-fancy-title-wrap" />');
        }
    });
}
```

I'd also encourage you to simply alter the success statement of the ajax call that is appending these elements, otherwise you're going to be calling fancyTitler on any ajax call.

Comment: Yes! That's what's working just fine! In spite of the fact that I'll have to modify a bunch of functions on the way you mentioned - it does the job. You saved my ass man, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly the problem is that you load some content with AJAX (NOT the javascript, but just some html content), and elements with the class `k-fancy-title` doesn't gets picked up by the already-loaded javascript?

When first loading the page, and when the document is ready, you fire the fancyTitler() function (`CHEF.fancyTitler()`). But when you load some other content, nothing in your script calls it again for the new DOM elements (which weren't present when the ready event got fired on the document). So `after` the new ajax content gets loaded, you should fire that function again. Something like the following:

```
$.get('/path/to/the/content', function() {
    // inside success function
    CHEF.fancyTitler();
});
```

Comment: I'm loading the content asynchronously by using `jQuery.ajax` and on success I can't re-call `CHEF.fancyTitler()` function - I already tried that. This function is undefined.